# SQLAlchemy declarative extension vs. elixir

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-elixir

I am planning to use SQLAlchemy in one of my projects and i am very interested in declarative syntax of tables.

I was told to use the [Elixir Declarative Layer](http://elixir.ematia.de/trac/wiki) for that, at the same time SQLAlchemy has its built-in [declarative extension](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative.html).

What are the current differences between Elixir and the declarative extension? Advantages/disadvantages?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957938/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-elixir

Comment: @robots.jpg, i've seen that question, but is has many question and is 1.5 years old. Is it still actual?

Comment: The latest Elixir release is from 2009, so not much has changed on that end.  I don't know if I can provide enough detail for a real answer, but the only advantage I can confirm currently is that you might find Elixir's methods of defining relationships more intuitive for simple projects than SQLA's declarative.  The other differences seem to be trivial.

Answer (score 12):

Elixir exists because SQLA Declarative didn't. Now that we have SQLAlchemy declarative, you probably don't need Elixir unless there's a specific way it does things that you prefer. Just be aware that Elixir is a dead project, and you will be stuck with an older version of SQLAlchemy.